# Segmented Control title shows on simulator but not device

Tags: ios

Here's what I see on the simulator:
[image: Good nav bar]

Here's what I see on the device:
[image: Bad nav bar]

This is the code:

```
- (void)buildNavBarTitle
{
    self.navigationItem.title = nil;
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, view.frame.size.height - 10)];
    segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"New" atIndex:0 animated:NO];
    [segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Today" atIndex:1 animated:NO];

    [view addSubview:segmentedControl];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = view;
}
```

I have

- deleted app on simulator & device
- restarted xCode
- cmd+shift+k to clean
- cmd+shift+alt+k to wipe build folder

Comment: are your simulator and device both the exact same ios?

Comment: they're both 6.1, but the simulator is "6.1 (10B141)" and the device is "6.1.3 (10B329)"

Comment: Does using the UISegmentedControl initWithItems: initialiser make any difference? Don't forget to set the frame after initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue when I used UIAppearance to style all controls of that type.  It had to do with when I was trying to remove the shadow from the text, it cause the text not to appear.  After allowing the shadow, you couldn't notice that it was really there, and the text reappeared.

I have submitted a bug to apple regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"New", @"Today", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray]
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 200, 250, 50);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```